# django-debug-toolbar looking for assets by relative path?

Tags: python, django, django-debug-toolbar

I'm trying to get django-debug-toolbar to work, and after following all the instructions, I'm getting these errors:

```
[05/Sep/2012 15:33:35] "GET /profile/edit/ HTTP/1.1" 200 43647
[05/Sep/2012 15:33:36] "GET /profile/edit/debug_toolbar/css/toolbar.min.css HTTP/1.1" 404 86163
[05/Sep/2012 15:33:36] "GET /profile/edit/debug_toolbar/css/toolbar.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 66260
```

The HTML source is calling these things relative.

When I grep through the debug-toolbar sources, I see these two lines line:

```
debug_toolbar/templates/debug_toolbar/base.html:5:<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}debug_toolbar/css/toolbar.min.css" type="text/css">
debug_toolbar/templates/debug_toolbar/base.html:6:<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}debug_toolbar/css/toolbar.min.js"></script>
```

However, my STATIC_URL is set to `/static/` in the settings.py file for the project. Did I misconfigure something here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I manually applied bugfixes provided [here](https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar/pull/317) and it did a trick for me.

Comment: now I get 304 errors instead of 404s... but whatevs' thanks a lot!