# Django-debug-toolbar not displaying (Can't find the .js and .css) and display is at "none"

Tags: django, django-debug-toolbar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [django-debug-toolbar looking for assets by relative path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12289349/django-debug-toolbar-looking-for-assets-by-relative-path)

So I just followed the instructions to install the django-debug-toolbar v0.9.4, and I can't make the toolbar appear in BOTH the admin and regular application. However, I can see it in the HTML source (via Chrome for example) and the display is set to "none". If I remove that style, it appears (without style and JS however) Also, it can't find the .js and .css.

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (NOT FOUND) 127.../machines/view/2/debug_toolbar/css/toolbar.min.css
>
> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (NOT FOUND) 127.../machines/view/2/debug_toolbar/css/toolbar.min.js

Here are my settings so far relevant to this problem: http://dpaste.org/ar9ji/

Comment: Where are you running from?  It would seem that you are running local.  Correct?

Comment: Great...  glad it worked.  I've flagged as a duplicate of the other question so that the moderators can handle accordingly.